# How to wait for login cookie in C# Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, c#, selenium-webdriver

Im only been working with Java before but need to set up some tests in C#.

In a login test I like to have a wait method waiting for the login cookie to be set.

In Java I can do something like this, but not able to create the same in C#, can anyone help me convert this code to C#?

```
    public void getTokenCookie(){
    try {
        wait.until(
                new ExpectedCondition<Cookie>() {
                    @Override
                    public Cookie apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
                        Cookie tokenCookie = driver.manage().getCookieNamed("nameOfCookie");
                        if (tokenCookie != null) {
                            System.out.println("\nToken Cookie added: " + tokenCookie);
                            return tokenCookie;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("waiting for cookie..");
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                }
        );

    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        fail("Failed to login, no cookie set");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C# I believe the above would look something like this:

```
public Cookie GetTokenCookie()
{
    var webDriver = new ChromeDriver(); //or any IWebDriver

    var wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    Cookie cookie = default(Cookie);

    try
    {
        cookie = wait.Until(driver =>
        {
            Cookie tokenCookie = driver.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed("nameOfCookie");
            if (tokenCookie != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nToken Cookie added: " + tokenCookie);
                return tokenCookie;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("waiting for cookie...");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{e.Message}");
    }

    return cookie;
}
```

In the dotnet bindings, `ExpectedConditions` isn't required when consuming `WebDriverWait.Until<T>`.  You can just send in a `Func<IWebDriver, T>` for your condition.

It's also worth noting that if `Until` fails to meet the condition it will check the list of configured ignored exception types before throwing. - [Details on configuring these](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/ceaf3da79542024becdda5953059dfbb96fb3a90/dotnet/src/support/UI/DefaultWait%7BT%7D.cs#L110)

For more details on getting cookies with the dotnet bindings check out the [ICookieJar](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/ICookieJar.cs) interface.

Additional info on custom waiting with the dotnet bindings in general can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339339/how-to-add-custom-expectedconditions-for-selenium).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and the code  snippet Jordan, really appreciated!