# Wait for cookie with Selenium python webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies

I basically here the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341417/how-to-wait-for-login-cookie-in-c-sharp-selenium-webdriver), only with Python.

I want to use Selenium to get the user to log in with a browser, then grab the session cookie that will contain the log in information, and finally close the browser. In an interactive session, it's easy to just wait until the authentication is complete before calling `get_cookie()`. But in run mode, I'm stuck.

From the Selenium documentation, I get that it is about defining a wait strategy. So I tried to repurpose their code example as follows:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('https://examplecom/')
sessionId = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=120).until(lambda d: d.get_cookie('session_cookie')['value'])

driver.quit()
```

Unfortunately, the following error is immediately raised:

```py
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

What should I do instead?

Comment: you know you can make a chrome profile and I think it will save any cookies in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duh! I was calling the `value` key as part of the wait function, thus even before it was available! This works:

```py
sessionId = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=120).until(lambda d: d.get_cookie('TK'))['value']
```

Answer (score 0):

To save cookies in Selenium, you can do as follows:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

expanduser = os.path.expanduser('~')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
```

and then add option of `user-data-dir`:

```
options.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={expanduser}\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\any_Name_You_Want')
```

and then create your browser with these option:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do. All I want is to get the value of the session cookie. Running driver.get_cookie() after the browser login does what I want.

Comment: what do you need the session cookies for @mrgou

Comment: Why does it matter? I just need it for the rest of my program.

Comment: I don't know if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15058521/17098450) answer can help @mrgou