# C# - Equivalent to java's ExpectedConditions.not

Tags: java, c#, .net, selenium

I'm writing some automated tests using Selenium in C# and I need to wait until a certain element is not in a Stale state. In java, I've once used something like `ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(element)`,
but I haven't yet found a way to do this in C#.

Is there a workaround for this problem or does Selenium in .NET not have the "Not" property at all?

Comment: Duplicated see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339339/how-to-add-custom-expectedconditions-for-selenium

Comment: Why not use ElementExists or looking for visibility ElementIsVisible?

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for this `not` method and it seems there is no **While** or **Until not** construct available for use out of the box in C# using `ExpectedConditions` enumeration. This is a difference compared to Java or Python.

However according [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21344534/2224701) you can rewrite the problem using lambda:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
{
    try {
      // Calling any method forces a staleness check
      element.isEnabled();
      return element;
    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException expected) {
      return null;
    }
});
```

Or you can use just another condition `ExpectedConditions.ElementExists`.